# Groovy implementation details

Tags: groovy, jvm-languages

Where can I find more details about how Groovy is implemented under-the-hood? Aside from the source code, are there good papers, blogs, videos, slide decks etc discussing the implementation details?

Answer (score 2):

Something in the direction of Scala sids, would be http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GroovyJSR/Groovy+Enhancement+Proposal
But there is a huge difference between Scala and Groovy, and I don't mean the typing. Scala is traditionally backed by science people. They write papers about it. The Groovy language guys are not working at universities and have therefore less the tendency to write papers. 
As for blogs, there are several,maybe http://groovyblogs.org is a good starting point. But really the best way is to just ask on more specific information on the dev or user list.

Answer (score -1):

A Groovy equivalent of Scala's http://www.scala-lang.org/sids would be nice.

Comment: Your remark would have added better value as a comment to the original question. Now SO won't show this question as unanswered, and hence might not attract attention from others who are capable of answering it.

Comment: @Binil Only just noticed your comment. My apologies. I was still getting used to how answers and comments on stackoverflow worked at that time.